# Jolt don't transform json to another json

Tags: java, json, spring, jolt

I am writing a project using Java 11, spring boot 2.1.9 and jolt (core and utils) 0.1.1 on Ubuntu

I have next JSON source:

```
{
  "restaurant": {
    "rating": {
      "value": 3
    },
    "address": {
      "value": "India"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the following spec file:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "restaurant": {
        "rating": {
          "value": "Restaurant Rating"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

On the output I expect next json:

```
{
  "Restaurant Rating" : 3
}
```

I wrote a simple test to check this:

```java
List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.jsonToList(Files.readString(Paths.get("path/to/spec.json")));
Chainr converter = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.toJsonString(Files.readString(Paths.get("path/to/example.json")));
Object transformedOutput = converter.transform(inputJSON);
System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
```

But variable `transformedOutput` always is `null`

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonToObject will get input json as object and map with spec

```
    List specs = JsonUtils.jsonToList(Files.readString(Paths.get("path/to/spec.json")));
    Chainr converter = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
    Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.jsonToObject(Files.readString(Paths.get("path/to/example.json")));
    Object transformedOutput = converter.transform(inputJSON);
    System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
```

----output-----

{
  "Restaurant Rating" : 3
}

Comment: Many thanks for answer! The answer helped me. Now the transformation works perfectly!